# Selecionando dados em cURL Java

Tags: java, json, libcurl

Gostaria de saber como selecionar os dados usando a biblioteca gson.

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    URL endereco = new URL("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/"+Server+"/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+Jogador+"?api_key="+API_KEY);
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(endereco.openStream()));
    Gson obj = new Gson();

    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close(); 
            } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }
    }
```

Tive como resultado isso:

```
{ "exemplo" : { 
      "id" : 1473077,
      "name" : "Exemplo",
      "profileIconId" : 25,
      "revisionDate" : 1355854041000,
      "summonerLevel" : 13
   } 
}
```

Comment: O que voce queria como resultados? Explique mais o seu problema.

Comment: Gostaria de pegar os dados e manipulá-los, com esse get eu pego todo o resultado, gostaria de separar. Selecionar o id e armazenar, selecionar o nome e etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu não tenho uma chave de API para testar, verifiquei o site passado e vi que tudo esté em uma [unica linha](https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/001/v1.4/summoner/by-name/1473077?api_key=001). Logo, nem precisaria de GSON para o parse (não use bibliotecas se não forem necessárias)

```
package data;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class semGsonExemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
        URL endereco = new URL("http://kyllo.com.br/GSON.exemplo");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(endereco.openStream()));
        String data = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("id = " + parseSemGson(data,"id"));
        System.out.println("name = " + parseSemGson(data,"name"));
        System.out.println("profileIconId = " + parseSemGson(data,"profileIconId"));
        System.out.println("revisionDate = " + parseSemGson(data,"revisionDate"));
        System.out.println("summonerLevel = " + parseSemGson(data,"summonerLevel"));
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static String parseSemGson(String linha,String campo){
        linha = linha.replaceAll("\"","");
        int indice = linha.indexOf(campo) + 3 + campo.length();
        int ultimo_char = linha.indexOf(",", indice)!=-1?linha.indexOf(",", indice):linha.indexOf("}", indice);
        return linha.substring(indice,ultimo_char);
    }
}
```

Note que coloquei o seu exemplo no meu site, apenas para que esteja no mesmo formato que a API te passa.